# OneDrive dirlist into SQL on LAMP

Tags: php, sql, api, token, onedrive

I am running a LAMP-docker container and need to get the content (dirlist) of one of my OneDrive folders in SQL. 
The OneDrive folder contains collected scanned expenses documents. All I want is to get the folder content (dir-list) in my SQL database. *Once the dirlist is in the SQL database some php-code helps me to filter and sort the list for analyzing and reporting. No download, no upload needed.*
I found some tips but most of the solutions seem to be an overkill for me.
I only need a simple OneDrive authentication method (token) and a remote dir > SQL on Linux console.

Any simple solution known by someone? Any tips? Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rclone did the simple dirlist-job for me.

```
rclone lsjson onedrive:myfolder > forimportintoSQL.json
```

more details here: https://rclone.org/onedrive/